# Strange sharp lines/noticeable seams

Tags: modeling, shaders, vertices, edges

I was making a model for a game, and I finished and had a look at the model. With shading turned to smooth, I noticed there were some strange lines along certain edges. I can't find anything close to this happening with anyone else. If i try to delete the vertices and remodel that same place they still appear. All of the vertices are connected to each other, and there's no duplicates or unused ones.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your mesh in edit mode so we can see the vertices.  Move one of the vertices and see if its connectivity is what you expect.  Lets see the rectangles or triangles present in your model.

Comment: It can be wrong face directions (turn on backface culling to see it and recalculate normals outside to fix it). Or may be there are duplicated verts (use merge by distance to fix it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the normals are inverted on them.
viewport overlays can help identify this (top right of the viewport, looks like 2 circles intersecting) select face orientation. should all be blue

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you. Some bits are red.